# Show that $\lim \sup |a_n + b_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r \text{ and } \lim\sup |c\;a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ be sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ such that for given $r>0$ we have

$$\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r \text{ and } \lim \sup |b_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r$$

I want to show that for $c\in \mathbb{C}$ $$\lim \sup |a_n + b_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r \text{ and } \lim\sup |c\;a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r$$

Basically, am trying to prove that the set $\mathcal{D}_r = \{ \sum_{0}^{\infty} a_n z^n\} \; | \; \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r \} $ is a subspace of the vector space of formal power series.'

For $\lim\sup |c\;a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r $ I used that $$\lim\sup |c\;a_n|^{1/n}  =  \lim \frac{|c\cdot a_{n+1}|}{|c\cdot a_n|} = \lim \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}\leq \frac1r \;\;\;\;\text{Is this correct?}$$

I have tried hard but I am unable to show $\lim \sup |a_n + b_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac1r $

Help would me much appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your argument is that $\lim \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ may not exist.  It is generally true that $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} \leqslant \limsup \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$, but the equality you are assuming need not be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definitions $\limsup x_n = \underset{n \to \infty}\lim \underset{k \geqslant n}\sup x_k$ and $\liminf x_n = \underset{n \to \infty}\lim \underset{k \geqslant n}\inf x_k$, it is not difficult to prove directly that

$$\liminf x_n \limsup y_n \leqslant \limsup(x_ny_n) \leqslant \limsup x_n \limsup y_n $$

It then follows that if $(x_n)$ converges so that $\liminf x_n =\limsup x_n = \lim x_n$, we have

$$\limsup(x_ny_n) = \lim x_n \limsup y_n$$

If $|c| \neq 0$ we have $\lim |c|^{1/n} = 1$. Hence,

$$\limsup |c a_n|^{1/n} =\limsup \left(|c|^{1/n} |a_n|^{1/n}\right)= \lim |c|^{1/n} \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} = 1 \cdot \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} \leqslant \frac{1}{r}$$

If $c = 0$, then it is a trivial consequence that $0 =\limsup |c a_n|^{1/n} \leqslant \frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: I just realized there was typo in my post, can you help me with the first summation upper bound?

Comment: @Abhay:  Are you aware that $|a_n+ b_n|^{1/n} \leqslant (|a_n| + |b_n|)^{1/n} \leqslant |a_n|^{1/n} + |b_n|^{1/n}$ where the last inequality follows from $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$ being a [concave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties).

Comment: thank you very much